# what is the optimized cufft library for tesla k20m card

Tags: cuda, nvidia, hpc

In our application we have FFT part. We would like to port that part onto GPU. We have Tesla K20m GPU. Which version of cuFFT is optimized for K20m card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a specific version of the cufft library that is optimized for a specific card. Just use the standard [cufft library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html) that ships with [cuda 5.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) (or [cuda 5.5 RC](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-pre-production), if you like).